# NewEnviron with a parsed but hidden body

Tags: environments

In the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcounter{totalmarks}
% \newenvironment{solution} {\par\textbf{Solution:}} {}   % Show solution
\NewEnviron{solution}{} % Do not show solution

\newcommand{\mk}[1]{\addtocounter{totalmarks}{#1} \textbf{[+#1]}}
\begin{document}

This is a question.
\begin{solution}
  This is a solution step \mk{3}. Another step \mk{2}
\end{solution}
\par \hfill (Total marks \thetotalmarks).\setcounter{totalmarks}{0}

\end{document}
```

The `solution` environment has the solution of the question. In some places, I add marks to the solution steps and then output the marks at the end and reset the counter. I have two questions:

First, using the `environ` package I am able to hide the solution as shown above. But this also means that my `\mk` commands are not parsed and I don't have a way to know how many marks the solution has. Is there a way to parse the body of an environment but hide its output?

Also, and this might be related, is there a way to show the total marks before (or at the top of) the solution rather than at the end? I know that can output counter value to an aux file and recompile but I don't know how to generalize to multiple `solution` environments in a single document.

Comment: Since counters are global, you could just execute the body of the solution in a savebox and discard the contents.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know about `savebox`es in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I provide a solution with `tcolorbox` package with the help of `refcount`, instead of `environ`, to solve both the hidden solution and refer-before-specify problems. The `tcolorbox` part is inspired by section 8.3 example of the package manual.

If you don't care about technical details, scroll down to read "How to use" section.

### Hidden solution

To hide the solution, I first come up with `tcolorbox` package since its `\tcblower` command provides an `invisible/ignore` option.

The background is set to white (`colback`), the frame is removed (`frame hidden`). Each problem is auto-numbered by the counter `tcbcounter`. You may change those style accordingly.

### Refer to the total marks before `\mk` commands

This is a little tricky, but `refcount` is the exact package designed for this. The key point in this part is to separate labels of counters with solutions (I use `rfc` as the prefix) and those without solutions (use `ig` as the prefix). The star argument of `solution` environment can tell these two types of labels apart, by using the `\IfBooleanTF` command from the `xparse` package.

### How to use

You can go through the following enumerated list, or just read my MWE for use.

1. Copy the preamble of my MWE to your preamble. My work requires package `tcolorbox`, `refcount`, and `xparse` installed on your machine.
2. At the very first of your doc (inside `document` environment), add: `\tcbstartrecording\relax`. Solutions are going to be recorded as separated files in your current directory.
3. For problems with displayed solution: use `\begin{solution}` environment with `\mk`. However, the last step should be applied with `\mklast` instead of `\mk`. To split the problem and solution inside a `solution` environment, use command `\tcblower`.

```latex
\begin{solution}
This problem asks ...
\tcblower
Step 1 \mk{...}, step 2 \mk{...}, final step \mklast{...}
\end{solution}
```

4. For problems without displayed solution: use a star-variant environment `\begin{solution}*` and star-variant `\mklast*{...}`. Don't need to change `\mk` commands.
5. After the end of the last `solution` environments, add `\tcbstoprecording` to stop recording solutions.
6. In case you want to display the hidden solution, add `\tcbinputrecords` at the end.
7. **Compile twice** to get the correct total marks. I've tested under pdflatex of TeX Live 2019.

### Minimal working example

Here is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

% Ref for the total mark counter
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcounter{totalmarks}
\newcommand{\mk}[1]{%
    \textbf{[#1]}%
    \addtocounter{totalmarks}{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mklast}{sm}{%
    \textbf{[#2]}%
    \addtocounter{totalmarks}{#2}%
    \addtocounter{totalmarks}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{totalmarks}%
    \label{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ig}{rfc}:\thetcbcounter}%
}

% Save solution for latter.
%   A modified version of 8.3 Example
%   of the tcolorbox manual.
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\NewTColorBox[auto counter]{solution}{s}{%
    %enhanced, frame hidden,
    colback=white,
    label={problem@\thetcbcounter},
    before upper={\setcounter{totalmarks}{0}\textbf{Problem~\thetcbcounter}:~},
    after upper={\par\hfill{\itshape\small%
    Total marks of \getrefnumber{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ig:\thetcbcounter}{rfc:\thetcbcounter}}.
    }},
    lowerbox=\IfBooleanTF{#1}{ignored}{visible},
    before lower={%
        \textbf{Solution of problem~\thetcbcounter}:~%
    },
    savelowerto={tcbsol\thetcbcounter.tex},
    record={\string\addsol{\thetcbcounter}{tcbsol\thetcbcounter.tex}},
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{no recording}
}
\NewTotalTColorBox{\addsol}{mm}{%
    % Copied from the `solution' part 
    before upper={%
        \setcounter{totalmarks}{0}%
        \textbf{Solution of problem~\ref{problem@#1}}:~%
    },
    after upper={
        \addtocounter{totalmarks}{-1}%
        \refstepcounter{totalmarks}%
        \label{ig:#1}
    }
}{\input{#2}}


\begin{document}

\tcbstartrecording\relax

With \verb+\begin{solution}+, the problem goes with its solution:
\begin{solution}
The problem is asking bla bla bla.
\tcblower
This is a solution step \mk{1}.
Another step \mk{2}.
Final step with special `mklast' command \mklast{4}.
\end{solution}

Use \verb+\begin{solution}*+ to hide the solution.

\begin{solution}*
The problem is asking bla bla bla.
\tcblower
This is a solution step \mk{8}.
Final step with special `mklast*' command \mklast{16}.
\end{solution}

This one is only for checking if the total marks is calculated correctly:
\begin{solution}
The problem is asking bla bla bla.
\tcblower
This is a solution step \mk{32}.
Final step with special `mklast' command \mklast{64}.
\end{solution}

\tcbstoprecording

% Show solutions on a new page
% \clearpage
For those whose solutions are not displayed above:

\tcbinputrecords

\end{document}
```

What does the MWE looks like:

[image: MWE pic]

Comment: Brilliant! This gives me a good starting point for a solution. I prefer to use a savebox as @daleif suggested.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to exploit that counters are global. Execute the solution body in a savebox, then discard the box. The contents are executed, but nothing is rendered.

*currently not at a pc so cannot provide an example*

Comment: Mmm... I am trying this solution but I just realized that `savebox` does not allow display math mode, `\[ ... \]`, in it. Any way to get around this?

Comment: Adding a `minipage` solved the issue with display math mode.